# How to convert Hierarchical File System (HFS) to FAT/NTFS?

Tags: ntfs, fat32, hfs

I know how to change FAT32 to NTFS file system and vice-versa. But I am unaware of [Hierarchical File System (HFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_File_System). So please tell me  if anyone knows how to convert HFS to NTFS/FAT32 ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: There is no straight forward way but there are [tools](https://www.paragon-software.com/technologies/components/ntfs-hfs-converter/) that allow that

Answer (score 1):

In case there is ever a need to format a disk with HFS, HFS+ or NTFS, you can boot from an Ubuntu live USB and install the following packages in the Ubuntu live USB:

HFS – hfsutils
HFS+ – hfsprogs
NTFS – Ubuntu can read/write files in an NTFS partition by default without installing any additional packages.

To install hfsutils and hfsprogs, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install hfsutils hfsprogs
```

GParted partition editor is an application that is able to reformat partitions/hard drives. To open GParted, boot an Ubuntu live USB, select *Try Ubuntu* and open GParted.

Note: When you boot from an Ubuntu live USB and select *Try Ubuntu*, it runs Ubuntu from the USB drive without installing Ubuntu or anything else on your hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Paragon offers a small freeware utility called [NTFS-HFS Converter](http://www.paragon-software.com/technologies/components/ntfs-hfs-converter/) that will convert whole volumes in both directions (but here is no FAT32 capability). The process is entirely automatic, only giving you a chance to create a simple backup copy before the procedure.

All three versions (including free) of [Paragon Partition Manager](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-personal/features.html) will also do this, with the addition of being able to convert between FAT32 and NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

For now, there is not any tool to convert HFS to FAT32/NTFS. Because HFS belongs to MAC OS, it can not support Windows OS. So, if you want to convert HFS to FAT32/NTFS, you can use formatting and choose FAT/NTFS.

Comment: There is no straight forward way but there are [tools](https://www.paragon-software.com/technologies/components/ntfs-hfs-converter/) that allow that